# How to remove all special symbols after : in EmEditor

Tags: notepad++, emeditor

Hello i need delete all special symbols like .,_- after symbol :

Example i got something like that

```
sfjsfajsafwp.pl:fsasaf.fssf
sfjsfajsafwp.pl:fsasaf.fssf
sfjsfajsafwp.pl:fsasaf.fssf.dgdg_
```

After this i expect:

```
sfjsfajsafwp.pl:fsasaffssf
sfjsfajsafwp.pl:fsasaffssf
sfjsfajsafwp.pl:fsasaffssfdgdg
```

Comment: Could you explain **exactly** which characters must be deleted? Do you want to keep **only** letters?

Comment: The question title says "EmEditor", neither the title nor the question body mention "Notepad++" yet the tags name both editors. Which editor (or editors) do you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^.*?:|\G(?!^)).*?\K[-.,_]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    ^           # beginning of line
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline
    :           # colon
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
    (?!^)       # negative lookahead, make sure we are not at the beginning of a line
)           # end group
.*?         # 0 or more any character but newline
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
[-.,_]+     # 1 or more any of these characters. 
            # You can add all the characters you want to delete
            # If you want to keep only letters, use [^a-zA-Z\r\n]+
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]